# How to extract Mobile number and email address from a specific cell of excel, having other text also available in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sample data of Excel cell:

```
Subject :Contact from Al Meezan Investment<br/> Email Body: Name: Gulzar ali mirbahar
Email: mirbaharg@gmail.com
Contact Number: 03412770800
Subject: Can I eligible of this offer
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

For data formatted like this (i.e., Email followed by Contact Number followed by Subject and each labeled as such), you can use the `FIND` and `MID` functions to pull out the email and contact numbers.

To extract the email, you can use something like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Email:",A1)+LEN("Email: "),FIND("Contact Number:",A1)-FIND("Email:",A1)-LEN("Email: "))
```

Breaking it down:
The `MID` function takes three arguments:
1. The cell you are extracting text from,
2. What character index the target text starts at (e.g., `40` would start at the 40th character in A1), and
3. How many characters to extract.

The first argument is just `A1`.
The second argument is `FIND("Email:",A1)+LEN("Email: ")`. This basically says the email address you are extracting starts at the index right after `Email:`.
The third argument is `FIND("Contact Number:",A1)-FIND("Email:",A1)-LEN("Email: ")`. This is a way of calculating the length of the email address.

Answer (score 2):

Although you didn't ask for a VBA solution, and you can certainly do this with formulas, for a more generalized solution, a User Defined Function (UDF) might be handy here.  You can extract the contents of any line that starts with a known label.

If you have more complicated extractions to perform, a different algorithm might be of value.

**Algorithm**

- Split the cell contents on the line feed character
- Split each line based on the desired `Label`

  - If the label is not present, the result of the `Split` will be an array with a single entry, otherwise it will have two entries
- If the `Split` has two entries, return the second.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=cellPart(A1,"email:")
```

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
'Extract any line starting with sLabel

Function cellPart(myCell As Range, sLabel As String) As String
  Dim V, W, X
  V = Split(myCell.Text, vbLf)

For Each W In V
    X = Split(W, sLabel)
    If UBound(X) = 1 Then
        cellPart = CStr(Trim(X(1)))
        Exit Function
    End If
Next W
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on the only example you have provided you can use the below 2 formulas

(*this will work on data in Cell A1*)

**Email:**

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("Email:",A1)+6,SEARCH("contact Number:",A1)-SEARCH("Email:",A1)-6)
```

**Contact Number:**

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("contact Number:",A1)+16,SEARCH("subject:",A1)-SEARCH("contact Number:",A1)-16)
```